# Intuiting the relationships between points in Gaussian Process with compact kernel

Tags: gaussian-process

I am doing some work modeling spatial data with Gaussian Processes.  To speed things up, I am using a [compact kernel](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.03673.pdf).  This makes it so that, over spatial extents that are > the bandwidth of my kernel, the covariance matrix is 0, which is hopefully a very large percentage of the covariance matrix.

The usual GP setup: I am trying to model a function $f$, I have data $\mathbf{x}$ and I choose a point $x^*$ at which I'd like to predict $f(x^*)$ using my Gaussian Process model.  Suppose that the bandwidth $\theta$ of my kernel function $K$ is learned already, or fixed.  Since my kernel function has finite support, we'll say that $x'$ is "within the window of $x$" iff $K(x,x') > 0$.  A point estimate for $f(x^*)$ [is given by:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_process#Gaussian_process_prediction,_or_Kriging)

$$\widehat{f(x^*)} = K(x^*, \mathbf{x}) K(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x})^{-1} f(\mathbf{x})$$

Now, I am having a bit of trouble comprehending the nature of the impact of observed points on predictions not within their "window" - viz. since my kernel has finite support, it would be intuitive to me that my prediction at $x^*$ would depend *only* on the points within the window of $x^*$.  However, the inverse of the covariance matrix does not really have this property: the inverse of the covariance matrix [can't be expected to have the exact same sparsity structure of the covariance matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/471136/inverse-of-sparse-matrix-is-not-generally-sparse).  So, my predicted value for $x^*$ will depend, generally, on my *whole dataset* including points $f(x)$ for which $f(x^*)$ was supposed to have zero covariance!

How can I understand the intuition here that $f(x^*)$ depends on values observed at $f(x)$, where $x$ is not within the window of $x^*$, despite the stipulation that the covariance between $f(x^*)$ and $f(x)$ is zero?

Comment: I do not understand. If $x^*$ is not in the support of $K(x,\cdot)$ then $K(x^*,x)=0$ and accordingly $\hat{f}(x^*)=0$, i.e. equal to the prior mean, as well. How does this depend on the whole dataset?

Comment: @gg Sorry for the bad notation.  I have a dataset $\mathbf{x}$ and $f(\mathbf{x})$.  Within that dataset are various individual observations $x$, $f(x)$.  Some of these observations are within the window of $x^*$, but not all of them.